# Terence Tao question related to Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I self-studying from Terence Tao. I got stuck on part (b) of this problem. If anyone could help that would be nice.

Lemma 14.8.14

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function supported on $[0,1]$, which is bounded by some $M > 0$, and let $\epsilon > 0$ and $0 < \delta < 1$ be such that one has $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x - y| < \delta$. Let g be any $(\epsilon,\delta)$- approximation to the identity. Then we have

$|f \times g(x) - f(x)| \leq (3M + 2\delta)\epsilon \ \  \forall x \in [0,1].$ 
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What is an "$(\varepsilon,\delta)$ approximation of the identity"?